# Make repeated ajax calls inside loop until condition is met

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am calling an API which has pagination implemented.
The response from the API is

```
{
  data {
    field1 : "value1",
    field2: "value2",
  },
  paginationKey : {
    id: "value for id",
    some_other_field: "value for other field"
  }
}
```

The value for the pagination key is specified in the request, and the response value for pagination key becomes the pagination key for the next request.
The value for pagination key will be null for the first request, and the final value of pagination key in the response will be null. So essentially  I have to call the API with pagination key value of null, then whatever value of pagination key I get in response, use that for second request and keep continuing until the value of the key in the response becomes null.

My problem is I am making ajax call using JQuery to this API like

```
let ajaxPromise = $.ajax({
  url: requestUrl,
  type: 'GET',
  data: requestData, // containing the paginationKey like I mentioned above
  // other parameters for AJAX call like crossdomain, timeout etc
})

ajaxPromise.then(function(data) {
  successCallBack(data);
}, function(error, errorMessage) {
  failureCallBack(error, errorMessage)
})
```

with successCallBack and failureCallBack being methods that I have defined

Now the Ajax call, and the subsequent callbacks being asynchronous in JS, I am having difficulty to make these requests in a loop, and break out of this loop when the response paginationKey becomes null.
How can I achieve this?

Comment: Is this through a public api you can share link to ? Are you wanting all the data pushed into a single array ?

Comment: Sorry, I can not share the API as it is not public. Yes, I want to store the data in a single array, but also update the result stored inside the array based on the response returned from every call.

Answer (score 2):

Since you need to wait for a call to finish before initiating a new call, you can use a standard loop. A simple solution is to call the API once a call is done, and the key is not `null`:

```
const repeatedAPICall = (requestData, successCallBack, failureCallBack) => {
  const ajaxPromise = $.ajax({
    url: requestUrl,
    type: 'GET',
    data: requestData, // containing the paginationKey like I mentioned above
    // other parameters for AJAX call like crossdomain, timeout etc
  })

  ajaxPromise.then((data) => {
    successCallBack(data)

    if(data.paginationKey) {
      repeatedAPICall(data.paginationKey, successCallBack, failureCallBack)
    }
  }, (error, errorMessage) => {
    failureCallBack(error, errorMessage)
  })
}

// 1st call
repeatedAPICall(null, successCallBack, failureCallBack)
```

If you need an array of pages, you can use [async/await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) in a `for...of` loop. For every key that is not `null`, we add the key to the array. If there's a key in the array, we make an api call, and add the result to the `results` array.

```js
async function repeatedAPICall(
  apiCall,
  startValue
) {
  const keys = [startValue];
  const result = [];

  for (const callKey of keys) {
    const data = await apiCall(callKey);

    result.push(data);

    if (data.key !== null) keys.push(data.key);
  }

  return result;
}

// mock api call
const apiCall = ((counter) => () => Promise.resolve({
  key: counter < 5 ? counter++ : null
}))(0);

repeatedAPICall(apiCall, null)
  .then(result => console.log(result)); // use your callbacks here
```