# How to wait for a function to execute completely inside while loop in nidejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await

I want to iterate next after the function executes completely. But, the loop iterates before the function is executed completely. I've used async/await. But no luck.

```
function getdata(a,b)
{
    var somevalue = '';
    request(req,function(){
        //somecode
        //assign value to 'somevalue'
    });
    return somevalue;
}

function abc()
{
    var value = '';
    while(value!=='x')
    {
        value = getdata(a,b);
    }
}


//I've tried this way

async function getdata(a,b)
{
    var somevalue = '';
    request(req,function(){
        //somecode
        //assign value to 'somevalue'
    });
    return somevalue;
}

async function abc()
{
    var value = '';
    while(value!=='x')
    {
        value = await getdata(a,b);
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to promisify the `request` call and `await` the Promise. Otherwise `return somevalue;` will run long before the request finishes. Plus, that code will spam the server with requests; maybe there's a better way to implement this than a while loop?

Comment: @ChrisG I'm crawling facebook posts and facebook sets callDirection to 'next' when all the posts are crawled. I need to check the callDirection. When callDirection is 'next' I will stop the process. I've another idea to do it. I'm working on that. But if i can solve it by while loop, I'll go for it

Comment: Here's a way without a while loop (and without await) https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/418atf9q/

Comment: @ChrisG also, if you kindly provide any code snippet or link of the solution that would be helpful

Comment: Also look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53240489/make-repeated-ajax-calls-inside-loop-until-condition-is-met

Comment: @ChrisG thanks a lot. I'm trying to promisify my request

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a callback function that will return only once the execution completes

```
function getdata(a,b, callback)
{
    var somevalue = '';
    request(req,function(){
        //somecode
        //assign value to 'somevalue'
        callback(someValue);
    });

}
var value = '';
function abc()
{
    getdata(a,b , function(data) { 
        value = data:
        if (value != 'x)
            abc();
    });
}
abc();
```

Comment: This will not pause the while loop though, this will attempt to run hundreds of thousands of HTTP requests.

Comment: why? at a time when value will be 'x' , next iteration will stop immediately . By what sense you say, hundreds of thousands .. please do clearify .

Comment: OP wants to only run the next request *after* the current one has *finished*, and for good reason. I assume that OP is making some API request and waiting for a specific reply value. Since we don't know when that reply is going to be `'x'` (or if ever), that while loop is running and running and running. It doesn't wait for the callbacks. It'll just keep calling `getdate()` and therefore `request()`, until the browser cannot open another HTTP connection.

Comment: Ok got it, I have updated answer that is now without while loop instead it is based on recursion.